# Skip rest of onClick if exception is caught

Tags: java, android, exception, onclick

I have a situation where I may need to prevent the rest of my onClick method from running if a certain value doesn't return:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    double a = 0;
    double b = 0;
    double c = 0;
    try {
        a = Double.parseDouble(((EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.area_a)).getText().toString());
        b = Double.parseDouble(((EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.area_b)).getText().toString());
        c = Double.parseDouble(((EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.area_c)).getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            //Exception here! Do not continue with the rest of the onClick method!
    }
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to skip the rest of the onClick method if the exception is caught?

Comment: Have you tried using `return;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting `return;` in your catch block.

Comment: Interesting. I did not think that it could be used in the way of canceling the rest of the method body.

Comment: That's the entire purpose of the `return` keyword. It returns immediately to the calling method (with an optional return value).